Connect SQL from Python in RHEL container using windows authentication
I created a simple python application which is connecting to an existing SQL db. I just want to run it in RHEL container using windows authentication for SQL, as I don't have SQL credentials with me. Please note, I can't use Free TDS.
I have installed msodbcsql17.x86_64 in my container using Dockerfile.
Getting error:

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Can someone please help me in this context. Thank you in advance.
Tried with msodbcsql17/msodbcsql18

"Windows authentication" relies on the currently executing process having an appropriate Windows/Active Directory token in its possession which it can pass along to services requesting authentication. Is the RHEL container using Kerberos authentication? Is it joined to the same authentication domain as the target SQL Server instance?
